# Getting radio button value data appended into a modal by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a list of radio buttons generated into a modal upon the user select the date and time once he sends a request. I want to do subsequent action where the user selects the timeslot generated onto the radio button and upon on click the confirm button, I will be able to get the value and move on to the other page.

I have currently console log and realise that upon clicking the submit button, my console values returns an empty array value.

Below are my modal html codes:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalNewAppointment">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select Appointment</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="modal">Select a Timeslot</label>
                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                        <div class="timeslots-section">
                            <div class="timeslots text-center">
                            </div> <!-- end timeslots -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="new_appt_cfm_btn" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> saving..">Confirm</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="close_btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below are my codes for data appending the timeslots into the modal:

```
$("#find_appointment_btn").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            let select_date = $('#select_date').val();
            let start_time = $('#start_time').val();
            let end_time = $('#end_time').val();

            let data = { select_date: select_date, start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time };
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "{{ route('assistant.newappts.get') }}",
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',  
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == ""){
                        alert("No available timeslots or Clinic is close!");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(data != ""){
                        $('#myModalNewAppointment').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
                        data.forEach(function(dt) {
                            $('.timeslots').append('<div class="timeslot"><input type="radio" class="timeslotchk" name="timeslotchk" value="'+ dt +'"/>' + dt + '</div>');  
                        }); 
                    }                      
                },
                error: function(error) {                   
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Below are my onclick method for my confirm button

```
 $("#new_appt_cfm_btn").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            let timeslot = $('.timeslotchk :checked').val();

            let data = { timeslot: timeslot };
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "{{ route('assistant.newappts.view') }}",
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',  
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);         
                },
                error: function(error) {                   
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: HI, remove space here `$('.timeslotchk :checked')..` i.e : `$('.timeslotchk:checked')..` and try again

Comment: oh my it was just a syntax error i guess. Thanks so much! :)